# How to programmatically click the jquery button and then get the return data using java

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

Hello I am newbie in Java. I want to get some data in a website, but the website is using jquery to produce the data. Is it possible to use Java to get the data? I have searched for some solutions but I don't really know how to achieve it. Some say to use selenium to load the html page. I have never used it before. Can someone explain the steps?

example: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Update: I may not have expressed myself clearly, I want to download the html information (e.g. table data) from a website. The problem is that the table is built in jquery. I have to manually click the next page buttons to load new data.

Comment: I solved it by using the curl command

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is possible to get the data from java. You must deploy a web project containing a java servlet on some server like  Tomcat , Jboss , Wamp etc. This servlet will connect to the database for you and fetch data for you. You have to send a AJAX request to the servlet for fetching the data. In jquery , you would write a function which would be called on click of a button. Instead of waiting for the click , you can call that function on load of your page.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to manually click the button and get the data...if you are deploying your site (if not a static website) then you must have some back-end database which will keep track of you data and you can fetch it as required.The link posted by you gives demo about how to use datatable to bind your data (a jquery implementation) but before using that you need to get it from somewhere ie may be from database...:D

**Just to explain,Here is the simple work-flow for Understanding how web works:**

[image]

when you request a webpage:

1. you initiate request by hitting url say
   www.demosite.com/indexpage.jsp
2. After resolving domain name(www.demosite.com) to an ip address
   request is redirected to your application server which hosts your site.(some additional steps also happens avoided as not needed here*)
3. Application server tries to identify whether it has the requested resource here "indexpage.jsp"
4. if resource is found, and if it needs some additional data (for eg. user profile info) that usually resides in
   database then application server call database server.(if resource not found it return 404 error that is displayed on browser).
5. database server runs a query on specified database.tables and
   returns the data back to application server.
6. Application server process the data and embed it in your page as needed (you decide where to embed what) and finally generates a pure html document and return to browser.
7. Browser parses the HTML and produces the output.

**To start with some databases with java:**
http://www.javawebtutor.com/articles/servlets/servlet_db_example.php or
http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-fetching-result-for-the-given-rollno-in-servlet

if any doubts feel free to comment :D